# Zend framework disable radio button in multioption element

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi I am trying to disable one radio button value at multioption element

```
 $elements[] = $em = $this->createElement("radio", "tshirt-$member",array(
        "separator"     => " ",
        "belongsTo"     => "tshirt",
        "class"         => "flow",
        "parentClass"   => 'renew-donation-holder',
        "label_class"   => 'span6',
        "multioptions"  => $options['options'],
        'value'         => ct_get($this->memSession, "tshirt.tshirt$member", $entry->athlete->tshirt_size),

      ));
```

try to disable it with radio button value

```
$em->setAttrib('disable', array( 'L'));
```

or to add

```
"disable" => array("L")
```

Is there any solution for this, another option is to add data atribute as some kind of flag?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are on the right track. Keep in mind that using this method you should specify the key of the associative array, not the value, depending on what your `$options['options']` are.

## Example:

```
$element = $this->createElement('radio', "tshirt-{$member}", [
    'multiOptions' => [
        's' => 'S',
        'm' => 'M',
        'l' => 'L',
    ]
]);
```

Disabling one (or more) items should now be:

```
// Single
$element->setAttrib('disable', ['s']);

// Multiple
$element->setAttrib('disable', ['s', 'l']);
```

Comment: Please don't accept the answer if it's not working for you. Also, please explain WHY it is not working so I might be able to help you.

Comment: Hey Bob radio inputs are still enabled, added data attribute into radio button, and disabled with jquery